# Cant share iCloud storage with family

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id, sharing

- I am a family admin
- I purchased a 200GB plan which allows for sharing
- I sent the share notification to family members
- I received the invitation as a push notification on the family member device
- When I click it, it will take me to the Apple ID setting in the Settings app
- When I click on iCloud and look at storage it is still maxed out (5GB of 5GB used) and my only options available under “Manage Storage” is to “Upgrade,” which then wants me to purchase a plan.

---

Note: I also cannot get purchased app sharing (not in-app purchases) to work

Comment: Does it show the 200GB available to you or is it still showing just the original 5GB? When I did this, I had to wait for the servers to provision the 200GB out to me which took a couple hours. Then after the 200GB showed up, I was able to share it with my family.

Comment: Good thought, but yes, it does show that I’m on the 200GB plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to contact Apple Support so they can "refresh your family members iCloud account". Dont tell them that specifically, but what can happen is that iCloud may not be acknowledging the change, and its something they can do on their end.

Other questions for you to answer: 
Do you see that family member in family sharing? 
Is it only that family member? If not call Apple Support with the other parties present (physically or 3-way).
Do they belong to another family?

Comment: Turns out I was doing nothing wrong. Apple had several errors on their end. Most of which are resolved now.

Comment: The right answer is to contact customer support.

Comment: Yep sometimes iCloud gets things wrong, a simple refresh tends to help.

Comment: I had this happen and i unshared my plan and reshared it and then it worked without having to call support

Comment: Yes that does work now